# Degree of homogeneity $ f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

> If $ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+y}$, then it is a homogeneous function of degree?

Do we need to differentiate to find the degree of homogeneity, because in its raw form it doesn't seem to be homogeneous to me?

[image]

Comment: Can you express $f(tx,ty)$ as $t^{?}\cdot f(x,y)$?

Comment: @Stacy You probably meant to write $f(x,y) = 1/(x+y)$ in the question?

Comment: @Brahadeesh, No its just f(x).

Comment: But what does mean with $y$? Is it a constant?

Comment: @MyGlasses I will upload picture of the question

Comment: @StacyBarrymore It looks like a typo. If it’s not $f(x,y)$ then the options don’t make sense.

Comment: @Brahadeesh I will confirm and let you know.